# Xamarin Forms Bind label text to value of dictionary

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am trying to bind my label to the value of my dictionary, so I would get a label foreach value in the dictionary. Now here is my code:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="categoryScrollView" HeightRequest="40" Orientation="Horizontal"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Frame CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="Black" BorderColor="DarkGray" HeightRequest="40">
        <Label Text="{Binding categoryCollection[Value]}" FontSize="18" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" x:Name="txtCategory" />
    </Frame>
</ScrollView>
```

And as you can see `categoryCollection` is my dictionary.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> _categoryCollection;
public Dictionary<int, string> categoryCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _categoryCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_categoryCollection != value)
        {
            _categoryCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

But after running the app, no text gets shown!?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That just won't work.  You can only bind collections to IEnumerable, and a Dictionary is not IEnumerable,  You could extract the values to a List using `categoryCollection.SelectMany (d => d.Value).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I would get a label foreach value in the dictionary.

Maybe you can use code to get each value from dictionary as follow :

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(){{1,"One"},{2, "Two"},{3,"Three"}}; 

for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", dict.Keys.ElementAt(i), dict[ dict.Keys.ElementAt(i)]);
}
```

However this can not be displayed in `Label` or `ScrollView` dicrectly.

I suggest that using ListView to display loop list , `ObservableCollection<Model>` can be used as `ItemSource` for `ListView` .Then it will be easy displyed in each cell of listview .

You can create a **Model** class :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int DisplayID {get; set;}
    public string DisplayName {get; set;}
}
```

Then in **ViewModel** can set sample data :

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get { return employees; }}

public ViewModel()
{
    // is set and the UI will react to changes
    employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayID = 1 , DisplayName="Rob Finnerty"});
    employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayID = 2 , DisplayName="Bill Wrestler"});
    employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayID = 3 , DisplayName="Dr. Geri-Beth Hooper"});
    employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayID = 4 , DisplayName="Dr. Keith Joyce-Purdy"});
    employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayID = 5 , DisplayName="Sheri Spruce"});
    employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayID = 6 , DisplayName="Burt Indybrick"});
}
```

Now in **Xaml** , add ListView in ContentPage :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsSample;assembly=XamarinFormsXamlSample"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsXamlSample.Views.EmployeeListPage"
             Title="Employee List">
  <ListView x:Name="EmployeeView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Not forget to bind ItemSource in **ContenPage.cs** :

```
public MainPage()
{
    ViewModel viewmodel = new ViewModel();
    EmployeeView.ItemsSource = viewmodel.employees ;
}
```

Here you can consider `ViewModel` as the `Dictionary` , `employees` contains the Key-Value data in each cell .In addition , you can add more property in `Employee`, then your cell will show much more styles.About [custom data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#data-binding) in listview , you can have a look at this doc to know more about it .

[image]

================================Update==================================

If need a horizonal listview , you can use **[CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list)** to implement it as follow :

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           ...
       </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[image]

There is [a sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/) for reference .

Comment: Yeah, but I want a horizontal view, so a horizontal Listview. Is that possible?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk It's possible . But you need to use `CollectionView` to implenent it . You can refer to this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list